# Detecting positions of two moving fingers

Tags: c#, computer-vision, aforge, motion-detection

I'm trying to detect the moving objects with my webcam, where I want to detect the position on my two fingers moving, so I can scale an image according to the move of my fingers, like if it was a touch screen, but I want to achieve that with camera and detecting moving fingers, so if I move my two fingers to each other the image get smaller, and if I move them away from each other the image get biger.
Here is my code:

```
MotionDetector detector;
BlobCountingObjectsProcessing motionProcessing;
motionProcessing = new BlobCountingObjectsProcessing();
detector = new MotionDetector(new TwoFramesDifferenceDetector(), motionProcessing);
```

What I get is many rectangles around each finger. How can I recognize each finger separately?
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Use RANSAC to fit two lines through the centroids of the rectangles, one for each finger. The difference in slopes between the two lines will give you an indication of how far apart they are. So the gradient of slope differences will tell you how to scale the image and by how much.